# Dynamically add data to columns in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I have the following code that dynamically creates columns within a WPF `GridView` control, the header names come from a `string[]` which is stored in a `List<string[]>` named `data_org`

```
GridView gv = tabell.View as GridView;

foreach (string s in data_org.ElementAt(0))
{
   gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = s });
}
```

Is there a way to add data while I'm creating the columns? I've searched for ways of doing it in the add column statement but can't find a way.

```
gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn{Header = s, **statement to add data to column**});
```

My data is stored in another `List<float[]>`, where each item `float[]` represents a column. Do I have to do something to handle that data type (`float[]`), too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not add data items directly to the columns of a `GridView`. Instead, you set the `ItemsSource` of the associated `ListView`, which is `tabell` in your case.

```
tabell.ItemsSource = /* Set a binding or assign an items collection. */;
```

Then you would create bindings for each column to the corresponding properties on your data items that should be displayed in the columns using `DisplayMemberBinding`.

```
var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn
{
   Header = s,
   DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(/* Binding property path / name of the property. */);
};
```

As you only have a list of `float`s for each column, you should create a suitable data item type first. The `ItemsSource` expects a list of items that contain properties for each column, it represents a row.

What you have to do now is:

- Create a row data type that contains properties for each column

  ```
  public class MyDataItem
  {
     public float Number { get; }

     // ...properties for other columns..
  }
  ```
- Create a collection of these data items with data from you float lists.

  ```
  var myDataItemList = new List<MyDataItem>();
  // ...create data items, add your data and add the items to the list.
  ```
- Assign the list as items source of the `ListView`.

  ```
  tabell.ItemsSource = myDataItemList;
  ```
- Add display member bindings for each column.

  ```
  var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn
  {
     Header = s,
     DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(nameof(MyDataItem.Number));
  };
  ```

Then it should work. However, I recommend you to have a look at the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: Big Thanks! My problem is that I do not know the number of columns before runtime. I only know that they are floats. So creating a row based class where each property represent a column is not possible as far as I know?